# Hibernate tries to (re)create existing tables and does not update tables

Tags: hibernate

I am using Hibernate 5.4.31 and have the problem that, even the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto value is set to update, hibernate always tries to recreate existing tables and foreign keys. On the other had any updates to an Entity are not reflected in the table structure. I think this is because of the try to recreate the tables on every startup.

Create, None is working as expected.

Florian

Answer (score 1):

After a lot try and error I found the reason for this behaviour:

For whatever reason I had the following configuration in my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
<property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults">false</property>
```

I did not know why someone add this peace of code to the configuration (it is an existing project). Looking in the hibernate documentation I found this defintition:

"This setting is used to control whether we should consult the JDBC metadata to determine certain Settings default values when the database may not be available (mainly in tools usage)."

I do not know why we should need this configuration and therefore I removed it and voila Hibernate does not tried to recreate existing table on each start.

Hope someone will help this.

Florian